# Getting an Android Guessing game to limit to three guesses only

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am doing an Android App Guessing Game and I can't seem to get it to limit the guesses to three.  Also, it generates a new random number every time the user clicks guess and I have no idea how to make it so that the generated number stays the same throughout the users guesses.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
package lab.mad.cct.c3375331task1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class Task1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int attempts = 0;
    final int maxAttempts = 3;
    Random randGen = new Random();
    int ranNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task1_layout);

        final TextView textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
        final TextView guessText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
        final EditText userGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);

        Button pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);

        randGen = new Random();
        // Generate number once
        ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);


        // When the button is clicked, it shows the text assigned to the txtResponse TextView box
        pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           String randText = "";
                           Random randGen = new Random();
                           int ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);
                           int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().toString());


                           if (userNumber > 19) {
                               guessText.setText("Please guess between 0 and 20");
                           } else if (userNumber < ranNum) {
                               guessText.setText("Your answer is too low. Guess again!");
                               guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                           } else if (userNumber > ranNum) {
                               guessText.setText("Your answer is too high.  Guess again!");
                               guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                           } else if (userNumber == ranNum) {
                               ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);
                               guessText.setText("You did it!");
                               guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                           }

                           while (ranNum != userNumber && attempts++ < maxAttempts) {

                               if (attempts == maxAttempts) {

                                   guessText.setText("You have guessed incorrectly three times.  The answer was " + ranNum);
                               }
                           }
                           randText = Integer.toString(ranNum);
                           textResponse.setText("");

                           userGuess.setText("");
                       }
                   }
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you instantiate ranNum a second time inside your onClick function. get rid of this. second: you should create a counter OUTSIDE your onClick function, to count users attempts and check for the counter each time user clicks.

EDIT: You already got your counter, you should only check for users input when attempts

```
public class Task1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int attempts = 0;
    final int maxAttempts = 3;
    Random randGen = new Random();
    int ranNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task1_layout);

        final TextView textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
        final TextView guessText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
        final EditText userGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);

        Button pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);

        randGen = new Random();
        // Generate number once
        ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);


        // When the button is clicked, it shows the text assigned to the txtResponse TextView box
        pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           if(++attempts>maxAttempts){
                               //anything when more then maxAttempts needed
                           }else{
                               String randText = "";
                               //Random randGen = new Random();  not needed anymore
                               //int ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);  will generate new random number every click
                               int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().toString());


                               if (userNumber > 19) {  //20???
                                   guessText.setText("Please guess between 0 and 20");
                               } else if (userNumber < ranNum) {
                                   guessText.setText("Your answer is too low. Guess again!");
                                   guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                               } else if (userNumber > ranNum) {
                                   guessText.setText("Your answer is too high.  Guess again!");
                                   guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                               } else if (userNumber == ranNum) {
                                   ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);
                                   guessText.setText("You did it!");
                                   guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                               }

                               randText = Integer.toString(ranNum);
                               textResponse.setText("");

                               userGuess.setText("");
                           }
                       }
                   }
        );

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've now managed to get it to have three attempts only.  It still looks like it generates a new random number every time but I can live with it as it is for now.  Thanks again

Comment: it should only create a new number onCreate. debug it and if possible show me the behavior of ranNum

Comment: I'm fairly new to all this Android Studio stuff.  If I debug it I just get the below information:

Comment: It's actually too big to copy here but I'm not sure it contains what you asked for anyway.  Is there a specific way I debug it because all I did was go to 'Run' -> 'Debug App'

Comment: by reading your code, i figured out, that your ranNum is always "resetting" when you guessed right. when your wrong, you show in randText your ranNum. check if it changes when guessing wrong.